# Concatenación de Regex

Tags: php, preg-match

Hola Tengo esta pagina WEB de donde estoy sacando datos para llevarlo a un array con el uso del Preg_Mach_all, los Regex de forma individual me trabaja correctamente pero necesito unirlos para que me creen un solo array combinado y poder usar la info en el resto del script.

¿Me podrían dar una mano para crear este array?

```
$texto="
    <a href="https://server.com/brazil"><img src="assets/images/flags/br.png" alt="br" title="Brazil" class="position-left"></a>
    <span class='channel_name'>(24h) 3 Palavrinhas</span>           
    <span class='titile_span checked_title ml-15' style='width: 50px'>Online: </span><div class='state span online' title='Online'></div>           
    </div>" title="(24h) 3 Palavrinhas">(24h) 3 Palavrinhas</span>
    <span class="label label-flat border-info text-info-600 get_vlc" title="copu m3u8" data-clipboard-text="http://stream-sky.cf:80/live/edvandro24h/4mRJSpRD1h/717100.ts?checkedby:iptvcat.com">copy</span>
";                  
        $title=">\" title=\"([^\"]+)\">"; //Titulo General
        $flag_countri="src=\s*\"([^\"]+).+?title=\"([^\"]+)"; //Flag+Country
        $state="title=\"([^\"]+)\"><"; //Online o Offline
        $url="data-clipboard-text=\s*\"([^\"]+)"; //URL
        preg_match_all('/$title.||.$flag_countri.||.$state.||.$url/',$texto,$matches);
        print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Qué es "Con Cadenación"?

Comment: No es Concatenación?

Comment: Ok Unir los Array generado por cada Preg_Mach, gracias por corregir hasta la ortografia :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me he tomado la libertad de modificar un poco tu ejemplo de más arriba. Dado la poca información y contexto que provees me limito solo a responder con lo justo.

Para concatenar los regexs hay diversas formas... Yo usaría la siguiente:

```
    # reuno todos los regex en un array
    $regex_array = [
        $title,
        $flag_countri,
        $state,
        $url
    ];
        
    # unimos cada expresión regular mediante el símbolo | (pipe, tubería, etc.)
    $final_regex = sprintf("/(%s)/gm", join("|", $regex_array));
```

Al final tu código se vería de la siguiente manera:

```
    $texto='
    <a href="https://server.com/brazil"><img src="assets/images/flags/br.png" alt="br" title="Brazil" class="position-left"></a>
    <span class="channel_name">(24h) 3 Palavrinhas</span>           
    <span class="titile_span checked_title ml-15" style="width: 50px">Online: </span><div class="state span online" title="Online"></div>           
    </div>" title="(24h) 3 Palavrinhas">(24h) 3 Palavrinhas</span>
    <span class="label label-flat border-info text-info-600 get_vlc" title="copu m3u8" data-clipboard-text="http://stream-sky.cf:80/live/edvandro24h/4mRJSpRD1h/717100.ts?checkedby:iptvcat.com">copy</span>
    ';                  
    $title=">\" title=\"([^\"]+)\">"; //Titulo General
    $flag_countri="src=\s*\"([^\"]+).+?title=\"([^\"]+)"; //Flag+Country
    $state="title=\"([^\"]+)\"><"; //Online o Offline
    $url="data-clipboard-text=\s*\"([^\"]+)"; //URL
    
    # reuno todos los regex en un array
    $regex_array = [
        $title,
        $flag_countri,
        $state,
        $url
    ];
        
    # unimos cada expresión regular mediante el símbolo | (pipe, tubería, etc.)
    $final_regex = sprintf("/(%s)/m", join("|", $regex_array)); 
    
    
    echo $final_regex;
    echo "\n\n";
    
    preg_match_all($final_regex,$texto,$matches);
    print_r($matches);
```

Puedes entrar [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/az1PYV/1) y ver como funcionaría tu regex

Comment: Funciona Bien pero al colocarle el | crea demasiado segmento de array. Probe con el PREG_SET_ORDER para organizalo pero se complico mucho mas el poder asignar valor a las varible por grupo resultante.

Comment: Utiliza PREG_PATTERN_ORDER  y luego selecciona $matches[0] el cual contiene todos los valores que han coincidido con tus regexs.

Comment: Heyyy... ese comando no me lo sabia HOY es un gran dia aprendi algo nuevo.. Gracias...!!!